# Enable autocorrect in Chrome on OSX Sierra?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

OSX includes pretty decent spell checker and autocorrect. Problem is, it's not working in Chrome, and Chrome is about everything today: we spend our days browsing, lots of modern chat & mail apps are just wrappers around web apps in Chrome window or some other browser-engine.

According to some technical discussions, Chrome decided to ditch Apple's system autocorrect in favour of their own spell checker, which works fairly well, but DOES NOT autocorrect things! It just underlines typos, but won't correct them for me, making it useless in fast-typing scenarios.

I found many questions (mostly dated 2015 and earlier) on the web about this matter, yet no practical solutions for OSX, which makes me wonder -- have we given up on this? Or there's some common solution that I missed?

Comment: Basically, Chrome just ignores the Mac toolbox & does what the heck it likes with most things. It does not conform.

Comment: 2021 and this still does not work. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I have seen many used is to use a Chrome extension like [Grammarly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammarly-for-chrome/kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen?hl=en-US).

**Just be aware that their privacy terms and/or security posture may not suit many users. See for example [source 1](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-safe-to-use-Grammarly), [source 2](https://techbeacon.com/security/grammarly-leaks-everything-youve-ever-typed-service-everything),** and much more info out there if you search for it.

Comment: Yes, I tested Grammarly. Looks like a decent extension, but it's way too slow for fast-enough typing pace and does not provide autocorrect, just suggestions. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes I forgot, Grammarly only suggests. But there is another extension you might want to try out, "Spell Bee" : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spell-bee/dfbnahffpakjbdlccohcoglcnafhgnhm/related?hl=en-US

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, just checked the Bee, seems quite limited in functionality + no support for languages beyond English.

And looks like there are no other extensions on topic. It's 2017, everybody is full on emoji already? Apple themselves seem to put lots of focus into emoji, yet spell checking been stuck for a decade and noone seems to care. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

The [issue to add Autocorrect to the spell checker on macOS](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7624) has been closed in 2021 due to lack of headcount on Chrome's side. It's unlikely it will be fixed anytime soon.